# How to simplify nested promises try catch?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function:

```
private bindSemanticObject(unom: number) {
    this.setSemanticService
        .bindObjectsSemanticByUnom(unom)
        .then(
            (addressSemantic) => {
                try {
                    this.setSemanticService.setAddressSemantic(addressSemantic);
                    this.setSemanticService.verifySemanticObject();
                    this.setSemanticService.setSemanticFields();
                    this.setSemanticService.saveSemantic().then(() => {
                        this.setSemanticService
                            .stateChangeBindObject()
                            .toPromise()
                            .then(() => {});

                        this.toastrService.success('Updated...');
                        this.editLayerFactory.destroy(false);
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            },
            (e) => {
                this.toastrService.warning(e);
            },
        )
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}
```

As you can notice this code has some `.catch` and one `error` block. How to simplify it and makre more readable?

Comment: Look into async/await

Comment: [Async / Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

Comment: So in the one error path, you're just dumping the error out to the console, but in the other error path, you're doing a toastr warning. Should those really be doing different things?

Comment: So, if to use async/await then to use outher try/catch block for all?

Comment: As result I need to show all errors in toaster

Comment: There's no point to `.then(() => {});` at the end of a chain, but it shouldn't be the end of a chain, there should also be a rejection handler. (That part appears within a `then` callback, but the promise created in that part is never used.)

Comment: This is not required promise, it means if it falls the outher promise should return data

Comment: @IvankaClerc - Doesn't matter, unhandled rejections are not best practice (and if this is Node.js code, may terminate your app entirely).

Comment: How to handle unrequired promise inside main promise?

Answer (score 2):

Here in 2022, you can markedly simplify that code using `async`/`await`, like this:

```
private async bindSemanticObject(unom: number) {
    try {
        const addressSemantic = await this.setSemanticService
                .bindObjectsSemanticByUnom(unom);
        this.setSemanticService.setAddressSemantic(addressSemantic);
        this.setSemanticService.verifySemanticObject();
        this.setSemanticService.setSemanticFields();
        await this.setSemanticService.saveSemantic();
        try {
            await this.setSemanticService
                .stateChangeBindObject()
                .toPromise();
        } catch {
            // You've said in a comment you don't care about
            // rejections on the part above
        }

        this.toastrService.success('Updated...');
        this.editLayerFactory.destroy(false);
    } catch (e) {
        this.toastrService.warning(e);
    }
}
```

A few notes on that:

- You've said that you don't care about rejections from `this.setSemanticService().stateChangeBindObject.toPromise()`, so I've wrapped it in an inner `try`/`catch`.
- You've also said that all (other) errors should be shown via toastr, even though the code in the question doesn't do that.
- The outer `try`/`catch` will catch both synchronous errors thrown by the code and promise rejections (because of `await`).

---

If you *can't* use `async`/`await` for whatever reason, you can use a series of `then` handlers:

```
private bindSemanticObject(unom: number) {
    return this.setSemanticService
            .bindObjectsSemanticByUnom(unom)
            .then(addressSemantic => {
                this.setSemanticService.setAddressSemantic(addressSemantic);
                this.setSemanticService.verifySemanticObject();
                this.setSemanticService.setSemanticFields();
                return this.setSemanticService.saveSemantic();
            })
            .then(() => {
                return this.setSemanticService
                    .stateChangeBindObject()
                    .toPromise()
                    .catch(() => { /*...suppress...*/ });
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.toastrService.success('Updated...');
                this.editLayerFactory.destroy(false);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.toastrService.warning(e);
            });
}
```

That's not **quite** the same, it doesn't handle a synchronous error from the initial `this.setSemanticService.bindObjectsSemanticByUnom(unom)`. If you need to handle that, change the beginning to:

```
private bindSemanticObject(unom: number) {
    return Promise.resolve().then(() =>
        this.setSemanticService
            .bindObjectsSemanticByUnom(unom)
    )
    .then(addressSemantic => {
        // ...
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, hwow to handle inner promise. It sends request to server and no matter result , the outher promise should work

Comment: @IvankaClerc - I've done that with the part I thought you said you wanted handled that way, `this.setSemanticService.stateChangeBindObject().toPromise()`, by handling errors from it inline. If the scope of the part you want to handle is larger than that, take that part as an example and generalize it. Happy coding!